# Opencv videowriter doesn't save video on flask

Tags: python, opencv, flask

i'm trying to save the output video.mp4 file to my dirc. it works individually, so i think my code is not wrong...

but when i use the function on app.py.  the terminal is showing, it is processing. but i can't get actual video.mp4 file.

what is the problem of this?

this is original source function what i'm trying

```
def video():
    pathIn=''
    pathOut = ''
    fps = 10
    frame_array = []
    files = [f for f in os.listdir(pathIn) if isfile(join(pathIn, f))]
    #for sorting the file names properly
    files.sort(key = lambda x: x[5:-4])
    files.sort()

----------


    for i in range(len(files)):
        filename=pathIn + files[i]
        #reading each files
        img = cv2.imread(filename)
        height, width, layers = img.shape
        size = (width,height)
    
    #inserting the frames into an image array
        frame_array.append(img)
    out = cv2.VideoWriter(pathOut,cv2.VideoWriter_fourcc(*'avc1'), fps, size)
    for i in range(len(frame_array)):
    # writing to a image array
        out.write(frame_array[i])
```

i tried individually the code and searched a lot about flask.

another function from other py is working well on flask. but only this opencv is not working.

```
from make_vid import video
@app.route('/upload_gpx', methods=["GET", "POST"])
def upload_gpx():

  video()
 return render_template('public/display_vid.html')
```

and my terminal shows
OpenH264 Video Codec provided by Cisco Systems, Inc.

this. so i think the video() is worked but i can't get my video.
only when i run the makevid.py, i can get my video.

i need help that how can i get the video using video() function on flask??

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: Why are you using duplicated in line and 5 and 11?

Comment: @toyotaSupra ah it's just my mistake:(

Comment: @Community idk how to show more about it, but i only use these codes and i should get video.mp4 file in my pathOut but when i run the app.py it seems video() is running but i can't get my mp4 file

Comment: Again. You have duplicated frame_array = []

Comment: @toyotaSupra yup i edit